# How to concatenate (or union) the results of find() from two mongodb collections in Meteor JS?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mapreduce

How can I concatenate (or merge or union) the results of find() from two mongodb collections in Meteor JS?
I preferably want to join them as a single cursor object, but fetching and converting to array would be acceptable. What should I use instead of  `UNION` in the following code? Note: I don't need to remove repeated elements. A concatenation is enough.

```
allLocations: function(){
   location_set_1 = TableA.find({'loc':{$exists:1}},{loc:1,limit:300});
   location_set_2 = TableB.find({'loc':{$exists:1}},{loc:1,limit:300});
   combined_location_set = ??UNION??(location_set_1,location_set_2)
   return combined_location_set;
}
```

A (n incomplete) solution may be the following but it will return an array. Instead I need to return a cursor object to the "helper" in Meteor:

```
a=TableA.find()
b=TableB.find()
c=_.extend({},a.fetch(),b.fetch())
// c=[].concat(a.fetch()).concat(b.fetch());
return c;
```

Comment: A (n incomplete) solution may be the following but it will return an array. I need to return a cursor object to the "helper" in Meteor:

    a=LocLogger.find()
    b=MessagesTable.find()
    c=_.extend({},a.fetch(),b.fetch())
    // c=[].concat(a).concat(b);
    return c;

Comment: Sorry there are actually two different tables. I fixed the post.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that ?

```
allLocations: function(){
   var location_set_1 = TableA.find({'loc':{$exists:1}},{loc:1,limit:300}).fetch();
   var location_set_2 = TableB.find({'loc':{$exists:1}},{loc:1,limit:300}).fetch();
   var result = [];
   for (i = location_set_1.length - 1; i >= 0; i --) {
       result.push(location_set_1[i]);
   }
   for (i = location_set_2.length - 1; i >= 0; i --) {
       result.push(location_set_2[i]);
   }
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Great! This solves the problem for now. But is there anyway to do it without actually fetching the data?

Comment: The only issue when you use .fetch() is that the resulting array will not be reactive if it is passed somewhere else. But in your case, there are no problem since where you call .fetch() the computation will be rerun when the data changes.
If you do not use fetch, you can use forEach : 
var cursor = Collection.find();
cursor.forEach(function(el){ ... });

Comment: And you can remove the two for block by using http://underscorejs.org/#union : return _.union(location_set_1, location_set_2) :

Comment: Thanks. Where should I call/use the "forEach" in Meteor? Inside the helper? or inside the {{spacebar}}s ?

Comment: Put the forEach computation inside the helper, on the client side. You can just call function inside {{ .. }}